# Determine equihash share difficulty

Tags: node.js, algorithm, cryptocurrency

I'm setting up an equihash proxy
I want to determine the share diffulty from mining.notify and mining.submit methods. So there are only params "JOB_ID", "VERSION", "PREVHASH", "MERKLEROOT", "RESERVED", "TIME", "BITS" from mining.notify and "WORKER_NAME", "JOB_ID", "TIME", "NONCE_2", "EQUIHASH_SOLUTION" from mining.submit

I've already tried methods from https://github.com/sammy007/node-stratum-pool/blob/master/lib/jobManager.js line 218. May be I was somewhere wrong

My code

```
var headerBuffer = job.serializeHeader(submission.nTime, submission.nOnce2, submission.solution);
var headerHash = this.hashDigest(headerBuffer, nTimeInt);
var headerBigNum = bignum.fromBuffer(headerHash, {endian: 'little', size: 32});

var headerNum = headerBigNum.toNumber()

var shareDiff = diff1 / headerNum * this.shareMultiplier;
```

job is BlockTemplate that contains params "JOB_ID", "VERSION", "PREVHASH", "MERKLEROOT", "RESERVED", "TIME", "BITS"

mining.notify already provides merkleRoot so block template contains it

SerializeHeader method

```
this.version = parseInt(this.blockVersion, 16);

this.serializeHeader = function(ntime, nonce, equihashSolution){
        var header =  Buffer.alloc(140+equihashSolution.length);
        var position = 0;

        header.writeUInt32BE(this.version, position);
        header.write(this.prevBlockHash, position += 4, 32, 'hex');
        header.write(this.merkleRoot, position += 32, 32, 'hex');
        header.write(this.hashReserved, position += 32, 32, 'hex');
        header.write(ntime, position += 32, 4, 'hex');
        header.write(this.nBits, position += 4, 4, 'hex');
        header.write(nonce, position += 4, 32, 'hex');
        header.write(equihashSolution, position + 32, equihashSolution.length, 'hex');

        return header;
    };
```

I don't know what exactly the output result should be but the actual result is very very low and resulting to 2.501061608547988e-10 and so on